# How to refresh/fix calculated creation date field (For different date format), "1899.Dec.30." error?

Tags: custom-list, calculated-column, date-format

I am using a calculated field in a custom-list `=TEXT(Created,"yyyy-mmm-dd")` to change the date format from the original `Created` date field. At 99% of the time works correctly, but in about 0.4% it result an "1899.Dec.30.". (After 2500 element there are about 10) If I look on the original `Created` column, the date is correct, only the calculated one is bad.

1. How can I prevent this error happening?
2. How can I refresh the value of these fields to show the correct dates everywhere? (Not an editable field)

Comment: You could change the sites regional settings to your local region and get correct dates instead of having the hassle of creating calculated columns. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-regional-settings-for-a-site-e9e189c7-16e3-45d3-a090-770be6e83c1a

Comment: Ohh thanks, that is useful to know. I don't know why did I find this solution instead regional setting change when I searched for this last time : /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I refresh the value of these fields to show the correct dates everywhere? (Not an editable field)

As it is a Calculated Column, you can delete and recreate it.

> How can I prevent this error happening?

This is probably a timing issue, and probably out of reach for an end-user fix. You could use a workflow instead to populate a normal Single Line of Text column. Workflows always run after the item has been saved.